# User folder from home deleted. Bad configured fstab can do this? (Solved, possible problem with subvol option in fstab)

Tags: kubuntu, home-directory, fstab, btrfs

Yesterday I install and configure kubuntu in my laptop and pc. Today I edit the fstab, when restart both, the folder of user from home was deleted. I couldn't login without the home folder of user.

In the laptop had problems with a mountpoint, probably fault of windows 10.

This is the fstab (it's of Debian, but I used the same options):
[image: Fstab-configured]

```
UUID="x"  /                  btrfs  noatime,ssd,compress=lzo,space_cache  0    1
UUID="x"  /home/user/folder  ntfs   autodefrag,compress-force=lzo         0    0
```

I have had this options with different partitions in Arch and Debian the last 5 years and haven't had any problem.I don't know is this can be the problem. But it's the single change that I can relate with the problem. I am so confused.

> SOLVED

Revising the laptop, I've seen in home folder there was a folder called "@home" where was all the data "deleted" of my  user and other folder called "@" with the data of root folder. Then I have seen in the fstab an option created by default while the installation of kubuntu, "subvol=@/home" for home directory and "subvol=@/" for root directory.

Comment: Please don't add pictures of code .. rather copy it to your question and use the text format tools to make it readable. I hardly can read the text on the mobile App but .. are you mounting different partitions to the same directory? Then I would guess only the last one stays mounted there while the others before get somehow "overruled"

Comment: Solved! Sorry for the picture, I just added the lines of fstab. No, are direferents mountpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revising the laptop, I've seen in home folder there was a folder called `"@home`" where was all the data "deleted" of my user and other folder called `"@"` with the data of root folder. Then I have seen in the `fstab` an option created by default while the installation of kubuntu, `"subvol=@/home"` for home directory and `"subvol=@/"` for root directory.